# Google Calendar .Net API V3 domain wide delegation

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm using,

asp.net 4.0, Google calendar api V3 and environments with windows 2003 R2 webserver with IIS 6.0 and we have our own licensed Google domain

My app needs to access lot of people's Google calendar and add/delete/update events  for which earlier we used V2 and was working with consumer key and consumer secret. currently my code is migrated to V3 version and it works, as I'm using service account type which uses API key and encrypted Key file. but my client is not very keen and they are looking at authentication similar OAuth 2.0 with Version V2.

so my Question what is the best approach other than service account with V3 to perform all the operations for bunch of users which should work on one time authentication like the one with V2?

thanks,
MVM

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar API V3 and Web Authorization. In this case the web page will be redirected to the User Consent Screen, and then end user should authorize the request.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

namespace Calendar.Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_HERE",
                },
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

            // Create the service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
            });

            ...
        }
    }
}
```